# Date Difference in MySQL to calculate age

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datediff

I have a problem regarding the `datediff` MYSQL function, I can use it and it is simple. But I don't understand how to use it to collect differences within the table field. E.g.

I have a column `dob` and I want to write a query that will do something like

```
select dateDiff(current_timeStamp,dob) 
from sometable 'here dob is the table column
```

I mean I want the difference from the current date time to the table field `dob`, each query result is the difference, the age of the user.

Comment: Wouldn't "the difference from the current datetime and a DOB" always be that person's age?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), dob)), "%Y")+0 AS age from sometable
```

([Source](http://goharsahi.wordpress.com/2007/08/18/calculating-age-from-date-of-birth-in-mysql/))

Comment: Returns Null
my date stored is m/d/year, for record which i am working has 1/1/1969 dob. but it returns null :( all the time

Comment: Using TIMESTAMPDIFF is a much better option

Comment: Missing if today is the birthday
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), '2000-05-19')+1), "%Y")+0 AS age from sometable

Answer (score 12):

You could do this

`SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, NOW()) AS`age`FROM your_table`

Works everytime.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, for each user, display the age in years, do

```
select name,extract(year from (from_days(dateDiff(current_timestamp,dob)))) 
       from sometable;
```

Comment: Returns Null
my date stored is m/d/year, for record which i am working has 1/1/1969 dob. but it returns null :( all the time

Comment: So what's the data type on your dob field? You really should be using a date/time type, not a plain text.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your comments on the previous answers, the date-of-birth column is not actually a `DATE` value but a string in the format m/d/y. I **strongly** recommend you change this; it slows down any date computations you want to do and you risk invalid date values getting entered into the column.

I think this is what you need. It uses the `STR_TO_DATE()` function and an algorithm for computing the age from the MySQL documentation:

```
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%m/%d/%Y'))
- (RIGHT(CURDATE(), 5) < RIGHT(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%m/%d/%Y'), 5)) AS age
FROM sometable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(now()) - TO_DAYS(@dateofbirth)), '%Y') + 0;`

Note: Give the D.O.B in the correct format, E.g. `YYYY-MM-DD'=> '1991-11-11`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), '2014-02-14');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select truncate(datediff(curdate(),dob)/365.25,0) from table;
```