# Finding the difference in days between different entries with same ticket

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table:

```
ticket    arrivaltime        resolution time    status

t1        '2012-09-03'        null               new
t2        '2012-09-04'        null               new
t1        (can be anything)   '2012-09-14'       verified    
t1        (can be anything)   '2012-09-16'       verified
t2        (can be anything)   '2012-09-06'       verified
```

Now I want to find, for example, for t1 the difference in days:

```
Age(t1)=(resolution time of last entry) - (arrival time of first entry)
```

Similarly I'll find it for t2.

How can I find this?

Comment: What datatype are the dates ?

Comment: By "first" and "last", do you mean the latest arrival time minus the earliest arrival time?  Or, are you referring to the ordering of entries in the table?

Comment: first means the "first entry" of that ticket and last means last entry of that ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT TICKET, DATE_DIFF(MAX(RESOLUTION_TIME) - MIN(ARRIVAL_TIME)) AS DIFF FROM TABLE GROUP BY TICKET
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link regarding syntax

[Date Difference in MySQL to calculate age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383516/date-difference-in-mysql-to-calculate-age)

```
SELECT TICKET, DATE_DIFF(MAX(RESOLUTION_TIME),MIN(ARRIVAL_TIME)) From TABLE
```

Comment: But how would I get it for all the tickets in one query